# Marking coordinates of the points plotted using gnuplot

Tags: graph, gnuplot

I want to plot my graph that connects a few point using 'linespoints'


I also want a label against each of the plotted point marking the coordinate of the plotted point. If possible draw a line along x and y axis marking the coordinates of the plotted points. 

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with vectors` option to draw arrows from column 1 & 2 with the length given in column 3 & 4. The `nohead` removes the arrow tips. And `with labels` you can place a string given as third column. The left causes left aligned text (i.e. right of the coordinates), and the offset moves the text one character width to the right.

```
plot "data.csv" u 1:2 with linespoints, \
    '' u 1:2:(0):(-$2) with vectors, \
    '' u 1:2:(-$1):(0) with vectors nohead, \
    '' u 1:2:(sprintf("x=%.1f; y=%.1f", $1, $2)) with labels left offset 1, 0
```

[image]

Comment: thanks... u cleared a lot of my upcoming doubts.I was able to remove those legends too by specifying title '' after the using statement

Comment: Yes, however, `notitle` is the correct one. You can also do `unset autotitle`. Then, only titles explicitely given by you are listed.